# How to configure Visual Flow Screen Aura components to use the same instance of Variable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a Visual Flow that consists of several Screen elements together with Lightning Aura components.

[image: Screens and screen Router]

A general idea of the flow architecture is that there is a Decision element called *Router*, which decides what screen should a user see based on the `activePathNodeName` variable, which is the Flow variable.

The transitions between screens are implemented using custom JavaScript logic in the component that every Screen has:

When the user clicks on the *Next* button, the logic updates `activePathNodeName` and dispatch *Navigate Next* event. The router uses `activePathNodeName` to calculate an outcome and automatically renders the requested screen

The `activePathNodeName` variable bound to a component using input design attributes and Stored Output Values (*Manually assign variables*):

[image]

*What works:* `activePathNodeName` passed to the Next screen
*Issue:* When the process navigates the user back, the `activePathNodeName` variable actual value gets lost. The flow loads last set value that was assigned into `activePathNodeName`. It means that I can't define *shared* state for all my Screen to define a flow pass it forward and back because every Screen element gets its own copy of the flow variable.

I've found that seems like it is *valid* behavior of the Flow: [Flow variable is getting lost after clicking previous button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51853/flow-variable-is-getting-lost-after-clicking-previous-button)

But, has anyone had a similar scenario, how to define *shared* state?

I appreciate any response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really interesting and easy.

When the flow process navigates back - it retrieves the previous state of the screen components and their own copy of attribute values. I've updated the logic of navigation so even if a user click Back it actually navigates forward meaning - create new Flow process screen with its own copy of attribute values.